# wrap text while user is typing

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a text area where a user types in. That text is rendered on a canvas while the user is typing in the text area field. so it appears letter by letter. I'm having trouble making the text wrapping work properly since it should happen while the user is typing.

I have a function drawtext(); that is called on every keystroke. The problem I'm having is that the previous line disappears when the text is drawn on the next line. I know that is because I'm calling a clearRect in my for loop. However if I don't do that then my text keeps rendering over each other. How can I solve this?

```
function drawText () {

var maxWidth = 500;
var textAreaString = $('textarea').val()+' ';
var theCanvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = theCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = colors[currentBackground];
ctx.fillRect(0,0,598,335);
ctx.font = "50px Interstate";
ctx.textAlign = 'center';

var x = 300;
var y = 75;
var lineHeight = 50;
var words = textAreaString.split(' ');
var line = '';

for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
    var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
    var metrics = ctx.measureText(testLine);
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,598,335);

    ctx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    var testWidth = metrics.width;

    if (testWidth > maxWidth && n > 0) {
        ctx.fillText(line, x, y);
        line = words[n] + ' ';
        y += lineHeight;
    } else {
        ctx.fillText(line, x, y);
        line = testLine;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops--my answer is a duplicate! What @Will Anderson says (I was typing my answer when he posted correctly)

Clear the canvas *before your for-loop* and then redraw all lines of text again.

Example code and a Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/7d5bs/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/reset.css" /> <!-- reset css -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    body{ background-color: ivory; }
    canvas{border:1px solid red;}
</style>
<script>
$(function(){

    var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

    var $text=document.getElementById("sourceText");
    $text.onkeyup=function(e){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
        wrapText(ctx,$text.value,20,60,100,24,"verdana");
    }

    function wrapText(context, text, x, y, maxWidth, fontSize, fontFace){
      var words = text.split(' ');
      var line = '';
      var lineHeight=fontSize;

      context.font=fontSize+" "+fontFace;

      for(var n = 0; n < words.length; n++) {
        var testLine = line + words[n] + ' ';
        var metrics = context.measureText(testLine);
        var testWidth = metrics.width;
        if(testWidth > maxWidth) {
          context.fillText(line, x, y);
          line = words[n] + ' ';
          y += lineHeight;
        }
        else {
          line = testLine;
        }
      }
      context.fillText(line, x, y);
      return(y);
    }

}); // end $(function(){});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <h4>Type text to wrap into canvas.</h4>
    <input id=sourceText type=text><br>
    <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: accepting your answer because my `context.fillText(line, x, y);`was also placed wrongly. thanks to your code I was able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Move this line out of the `for` loop. You're clearing the canvas before you draw each line, so only the last line will be visible when the loop finishes.

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0,598,335);
```