# How can i see text as i type when i draw text on image canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, drawtext

I have a canvas setup that allows an image to be uploaded and displayed on the canvas to draw text on the image by grabbing the user input when the sumbit button is clicked. I would like to see the text on image as it is being typed not when i click the submit button.

My index.html.erb

```
<canvas id="imageCanvas"></canvas>
<input type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader"/>
<input id="text" type="text" placeholder="your text" style="width: 300px; 
height: 28px; z-index: 0;"></input>
<button id="entertext">Submit</button>
```

My javascript

```
$(function() {

var imageLoader = document.getElementById('imageLoader');
imageLoader.addEventListener('change', handleImage, false);
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

function handleImage(e){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(event){
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function(){
            canvas.width = img.width;
            canvas.height = img.height;
            ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);    
            ctx.font = "40pt Calibri";
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            $('#entertext').click(function(){
                ctx.fillText($("#text").val(), 30, 40);
            });  
        }    

        img.src = event.target.result;
   }

   reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);  
}

});
```

Comment: Here's a previous Stackoverflow post that shows how to listen for keyup events on the input and redraw the canvas to reflect the changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033735/wrap-text-while-user-is-typing/23034243#23034243

Comment: @markE dont understand this please help me out. I know in my code i have a function which handle's the image to read a new file and upon load, a new image variable is created, which upon load draws text to the image loaded. Your tutorial writes the text in a new created canvas. Would like to implement the wrap text function also.

Comment: You can substitute your canvas -- just reference #imageCanvas instead of #canvas.When the user types a new character into the input element: (1) Erase the canvas with `clearRect`, (2) Redraw the image with `drawImage`, (3) Draw the current text with `fillText` as in the linked code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should put this code:

```
ctx.fillText($("#text").val(), 30, 40);
```

into `$("#text").on("change", function() { ... here ... })` handler.

Comment: its not still working. edited it to that and still cant see text written on image as I type. think it has to do with a keyup(); method